# UINavigationController for infinite navigation (nested folders)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I need to navigate inside folders and files in directory (from server). The problem is that I don't know the number of folders so it's not possible to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` statically. How can I use navigation controller with dynamically number of view controllers in swift? I want to "push" a new view controller every time a user tap on a folder in order to list files/folders inside it and I want to do it with UINavigationController so the user have the possibility to go back with "previous" button.

Both storyboard and programmatically approaches are ok.

Thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storyboards and segues are just a crutch. Think about how you would do this without them. At each level, to go down a level, you would just instantiate a new view controller and push it onto the navigation controller stack with `pushViewController:animated:`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:

And in fact it takes only one view controller class to do this, since any instance can create and push another instance of its own class. The display of one folder is exactly like the display of any other.

So if you wanted to configure this notion in a storyboard, you would have a circular segue, that is, the view controller would have a push / show segue leading to *itself*.

Comment: Thanks man thats right. I solved pushing new instance of view controller!

Comment: @matt, any idea for the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53047752/unlimited-navigation-stack

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @matt's answer, just create the controller and *push* it.  For sake of completeness, you *can* do this in a Storyboard with a segue.

Here's how:

1. So that you can call the segue *programmatically*, add an additional *prototype cell* to your tableView.  (You do this because you don't want the segue to be automatically triggered when the tableViewCell is selected.  By using an additional prototype cell, the segue can be wired up, but it will never be triggered automatically since this prototype cell will never actually be instantiated.)
2. <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from this prototype cell to the viewController icon at the top of the tableViewController.  Select `"Show"` from the pop-up.
3. Find this segue in the *Document Outline View* and give it an identifier such as `"showFolderSegue"` in the *Attributes Inspector*.
4. Now, when you want to trigger the segue, call: `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showFolderSegue", sender: self)`
5. You can use `prepareForSegue` to set up the new tableViewController as you normally would.

This method too works with a single tableViewController.

Comment: Actually I did it programmatically but I have a problem. My class has a list of objects which I display in table view. When a user tap on a folder I instantiate a new view controller and I push it in the nav controller. Now when you use "back" button the array which contains the objects results wrong, it doesn't contains the previous list of objects! Do you have any idea? My code is:
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle:nil)
                    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("id") as! CustomVC
                    vc.listOfFiles = sefl.listOfFiles

Comment: That sounds correct to me.  If it continues to confound you, it sounds like a good topic for a new question.