# Unlimited Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, swift

I have recently had an interview.

I had been asked to how to handle unlimited navigation controller like wikipedia or IMDB.

If we stack many `UIViewControllers` onto `NavigationController`, then I get memory warning or crashed by memory issue.

I wonder how this issue could be handled or what approach would work?

Answer (score 1):

A `UINavigationController` keeps an array of the view controllers in it's stack in memory. It does not seem suited to the task.

It seems to me the solution would be a parent view controller styled after a navigation controller, but that requires it's child view controllers to conform to a serialization/deserialization protocol (`Codable` would be a decent choice.) Let's call it InfiniteNavigationController. This `InfiniteNavigationController` would serialize child view controllers when they get pushed down on the navigation stack, and deserialize them when they need to be displayed at the top of the stack.

To be truly infinite it should probably save it's stack of deserialized child view controllers to disk, (and have a random-access way of fetching a child's data without reading the entire view controller's stack into memory) although that might not be necessary in practice because the serialized view controller stack should have pretty low memory requirements.

Comment: interesting! could you please add pseudo approach, or few lines of code?

Comment: I made that up on the spot. What I posted is the outline of an approach. I don't have any code, since I've never had to tackle this specific problem.

Comment: Hi Duncan, I understand. If you have time sooner or later, could you please include a sample code to see better picture.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you should create an observer that looks on viewControllers array (obvious) in navigation stack and condition that removes one(or many) from stack but it remembers their position and model that were using to provide data to draw ViewController. It can be written to disk using serialization to free the memory.

Apple also has [interesting mechanism to restore viewcontrollers state](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html) but i'm not sure that it acceptable to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily implemented using [UINavigationController.setViewControllers(_:animated)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers)

The trick is that you have always only one controller on the stack and instead of popping a controller, you first add it to the stack and pop to it:

```
let currentControllers = navigationController.viewControllers 
let previousController: UIViewController = ...
navigatonController.setViewControllers([previousController, currentControllers.last!], animated: false]
navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
```

and when you want to push:

```
let nextController: UIViewController = ...
navigatonController.setViewControllers([nextController], animated: true)
```

You also have to make sure that you don't keep the controllers in memory - you have to recreate the all the time, otherwise the memory consumption won't improve.

Another, more complex solution is to implement your own container component, adding a `UINavigationBar` to the top. The only problem with this solution is the fact that the animation will be slightly different then the `UINavigationController` animation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage

```
navigation.viewControllers = []
```

Comment: I was thinking to use `tableviewcell`l approach? What do you think? `TableViewController`  reuses tableviewcell with `dequeueReusableCell`.

Comment: do you want a vertical navigation ?? btw you need a similar cell so do your vcs have same look ??

Comment: Himmm, yes you are right. It is a good catch. Never mind, you have proved that my approach is totally false.

Comment: playing with **viewControllers** is the recommended approach

Comment: what is the implementation of `toNewNavigation()` method? How do you also store all UIViewControllers on the NavigationController?

Comment: it's another navigation for separation purposes